# Grab a value of each "home team" in R

Tags: r

Does anyone know how to do the following:

I have a dataframe (see sample below) that consists of two teams per match_id, team formations and actions (e.g. passes and tackles) in soccermatches. I want to create a variable "home_team", that captures each of the first team formations when a new match_id appears. In the example this would be 433, 4222 and 433 again.

```
dat <- data.frame(
  match_id  = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
  team_name = c("Barcelona", "Valencia", "Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona", "Getafe", "Barcelona",
                "Getafe", "Getafe", "Getafe", "Barcelona", "Getafe", "Getafe", "Getafe", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Barcelona"),
  tactics.formation = c(433, 442, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4222, 433, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 433, 4132),
  id = seq(1:22),
  actions = c("STARTING XI", "STARTING XI", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", "dribble", "STARTING XI", "STARTING XI", 
             "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", "dribble", "tackle", "pass", "dribble", "pass", "STARTING XI", "STARTING XI")
)

dat

   match_id   team_name tactics.formation id     actions
1         1   Barcelona               433  1 STARTING XI
2         1    Valencia               442  2 STARTING XI
3         1   Barcelona                NA  3        pass
4         1   Barcelona                NA  4        pass
5         1   Barcelona                NA  5        pass
6         1   Barcelona                NA  6        pass
7         1   Barcelona                NA  7     dribble
8         1   Barcelona                NA  8     dribble
9         2      Getafe              4222  9 STARTING XI
10        2   Barcelona               433 10 STARTING XI
11        2      Getafe                NA 11        pass
12        2      Getafe                NA 12        pass
13        2      Getafe                NA 13        pass
14        2   Barcelona                NA 14        pass
15        2      Getafe                NA 15     dribble
16        2      Getafe                NA 16     dribble
17        2      Getafe                NA 17      tackle
18        2   Barcelona                NA 18        pass
19        2   Barcelona                NA 19     dribble
20        2   Barcelona                NA 20        pass
21        3 Real Madrid               433 21 STARTING XI
22        3   Barcelona              4132 22 STARTING XI
```

Now I want to create a new column that classifies whether a team is playing a home game. It is considered a home game when a new match_id appears. However, I don't really know how to iterate this.

Final example should look like this:

```
dat_new <- data.frame(
  match_id =  c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3),
  team_name = c("Barcelona", "Valencia", "Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona","Barcelona", "Getafe", "Barcelona",
                "Getafe", "Getafe", "Getafe", "Barcelona", "Getafe", "Getafe", "Getafe", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Barcelona", "Real Madrid", "Barcelona"),
  tactics.formation = c(433, 442, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 4222, 433, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 433, 4132),
  id = seq(1:22),
  actions = c("STARTING XI", "STARTING XI", "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", "dribble", "STARTING XI", "STARTING XI", 
              "pass", "pass", "pass", "pass", "dribble", "dribble", "tackle", "pass", "dribble", "pass", "STARTING XI", "STARTING XI"),
  home_team = c("TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "TRUE",
                "TRUE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE")
)

dat_new

   match_id   team_name tactics.formation id     actions home_team
1         1   Barcelona               433  1 STARTING XI      TRUE
2         1    Valencia               442  2 STARTING XI     FALSE
3         1   Barcelona                NA  3        pass      TRUE
4         1   Barcelona                NA  4        pass      TRUE
5         1   Barcelona                NA  5        pass      TRUE
6         1   Barcelona                NA  6        pass      TRUE
7         1   Barcelona                NA  7     dribble      TRUE
8         1   Barcelona                NA  8     dribble      TRUE
9         2      Getafe              4222  9 STARTING XI      TRUE
10        2   Barcelona               433 10 STARTING XI     FALSE
11        2      Getafe                NA 11        pass      TRUE
12        2      Getafe                NA 12        pass      TRUE
13        2      Getafe                NA 13        pass      TRUE
14        2   Barcelona                NA 14        pass     FALSE
15        2      Getafe                NA 15     dribble      TRUE
16        2      Getafe                NA 16     dribble      TRUE
17        2      Getafe                NA 17      tackle      TRUE
18        2   Barcelona                NA 18        pass     FALSE
19        2   Barcelona                NA 19     dribble     FALSE
20        2   Barcelona                NA 20        pass     FALSE
21        3 Real Madrid               433 21 STARTING XI      TRUE
22        3   Barcelona              4132 22 STARTING XI     FALSE
```

Anyone that could help? :)

Comment: If `home_team` is when a new `match_id` appears, and that only happens 3 times, why are there so many `TRUE` values in the expected output?

Comment: I need to know for every action that is made, whether it is done by the `home_team` or not (for further analysis). So for `match_id == 1`, all actions made by Barcelona should retrieve the value TRUE for `home_team`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `new_match` indexes by shifting `match_id` and subtracting from `match_id`:

```r
new_match <- as.logical(dat$match_id - c(FALSE, head(dat$match_id, -1)))

#  [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Set the `home_team` to `team_name` for each `new_match` and use [**`na.locf()`**](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/zoo/versions/1.8-9/topics/na.locf) to propagate the missing values:

```r
library(zoo)
dat$home_team <- na.locf(ifelse(new_match, dat$team_name, NA))

#    match_id   team_name tactics.formation id     actions   home_team
# 1         1   Barcelona               433  1 STARTING XI   Barcelona
# 2         1    Valencia               442  2 STARTING XI   Barcelona
# 3         1   Barcelona                NA  3        pass   Barcelona
# ...
# 19        2   Barcelona                NA 19     dribble      Getafe
# 20        2   Barcelona                NA 20        pass      Getafe
# 21        3 Real Madrid               433 21 STARTING XI Real Madrid
# 22        3   Barcelona              4132 22 STARTING XI Real Madrid
```

Then check if `team_name` matches `home_team`:

```r
dat$home_team <- dat$team_name == dat$home_team

#    match_id   team_name tactics.formation id     actions home_team
# 1         1   Barcelona               433  1 STARTING XI      TRUE
# 2         1    Valencia               442  2 STARTING XI     FALSE
# 3         1   Barcelona                NA  3        pass      TRUE
# 4         1   Barcelona                NA  4        pass      TRUE
# 5         1   Barcelona                NA  5        pass      TRUE
# 6         1   Barcelona                NA  6        pass      TRUE
# 7         1   Barcelona                NA  7     dribble      TRUE
# 8         1   Barcelona                NA  8     dribble      TRUE
# 9         2      Getafe              4222  9 STARTING XI      TRUE
# 10        2   Barcelona               433 10 STARTING XI     FALSE
# 11        2      Getafe                NA 11        pass      TRUE
# 12        2      Getafe                NA 12        pass      TRUE
# 13        2      Getafe                NA 13        pass      TRUE
# 14        2   Barcelona                NA 14        pass     FALSE
# 15        2      Getafe                NA 15     dribble      TRUE
# 16        2      Getafe                NA 16     dribble      TRUE
# 17        2      Getafe                NA 17      tackle      TRUE
# 18        2   Barcelona                NA 18        pass     FALSE
# 19        2   Barcelona                NA 19     dribble     FALSE
# 20        2   Barcelona                NA 20        pass     FALSE
# 21        3 Real Madrid               433 21 STARTING XI      TRUE
# 22        3   Barcelona              4132 22 STARTING XI     FALSE
```